# Extension of the field of a matrix vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, spectral-theory, cayley-hamilton

A pretty common step that I'm encountering in linear algebra proofs is "extending the field" in which a matrix is defined. I'll make some examples:

**Cayley-Hamilton theorem**

The book I'm using proves Cayley-Hamilton theorem for triangulable endomorphism, and than it states that it's valid for any endomorphism because a matrix over a field $F$ can be seen as a matrix over the algebraic closure of that field $F'$. Clearly the algebraic closure is algebrically closed(and the water is wet), so any matrix is triangulable over $F'$ and clearly the characteristic polynomial doesn't depend upon the chosen field($F$ or $F'$). So any matrix over any field is a zero of its characteristic polynomial and **by isomorphism** every endomorphism is a zero of its characteristic polynomial.

**Existence of eigenvalues of a symmetric endomorphism**

My book proves first that an hermitian endomorphisms has real eigenvalues. Then it states that a real symmetric matrix can be seen as an hermitian matrix over $\mathbb{C}$, so it has only real eigenvalues(that are also eigenvalues of the starting matrix over real numbers, since they are real). So any symmetric matrix has  eigenvalues and **by isomorphism** every symmetric endomorphism has eigenvalues.

In general I don't like proofs with matrices(I know, I'm quirky), I prefer working always with endomorphisms. Clearly I perfectly know that matrix and endomorphisms algebras are isomorphic and it's because of this, that I think that we should be able to complete the proofs above without the use of matrices, but only with endomorphisms. Is there a way to "extend the field of scalars" to make this kind of passage meaningful also in "endomorphism language".

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don’t think preferring morphisms over matrices is quirky. In fact I find it more natural, since it does not involve the choice of a basis and you don’t have to think about invariance under equivalence of matrices all the time...

Comment: @PrudiiArca thank you, I felt really alone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is yes. In the most general setting, extending the field of scalars is done via the (appropriately named) [extension of scalars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change_of_rings#Extension_of_scalars).  Of particular note is the notion of [complexification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complexification). Note also that a "complexified" real vector space is sometimes referred to as a [linear complex structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_complex_structure).

Whatever your field $F$, it is not too difficult to establish that there exists a sensible notion of multiplication by the extended field $F'$. The "tricky" parts are usually related to how the original vector space "fits" within this extended structure.  For example: the complex eigenvalues and eigenvectors of a real matrix come in complex-conjugate pairs; coming up with (and proving) an [analogous statement](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1873167/81360) for endomorphisms over a complexified vector space means that we need to say what exactly "having real entries" should mean in the abstracted context.

Comment: Thank you , it seems really interesting.